# while doing alter on a table to add column we are getting timing out error via flyway

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, flyway, mariasql

we are using flyway to do schema changes which is on MARIA DATABASE. while doing alter on a table we are getting timing out error via flyway. Alter table is just adding a column. this script is executing via flyway on spring boot application.

classification table has 900k records.

this is the script:

```
ALTER TABLE  wallet.wallet_debit 
ADD COLUMN tin_code varchar(45) ;
```

When I ran alter table to add column via MySQL workbench , it ran in few seconds successfully.

ERROR is **only** coming via flyway while executing that script